# Push elements from arrays into a single array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

My Document Structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59edc58af33e9b5988b875fa"),
    "Agent" : {
        "Name" : "NomanAgent",
        "Location" : "Lahore",
        "AgentId" : 66,
        "Reward" : "Thumb Up",
        "Suggestion" : [ 
            "Knowledge", 
            "Professionalisn"
        ]
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve in this query:
I want to find the count of each suggestion given by a customer to every agent, it should look something like,

```
{
    "AgentName": "Xyz",
    "SuggestionCounts": {
         "Knowledge": 2,
         "Professionalism": 3,
         "Friendliness": 1
     }
}
```

What I have done so far,

```
db.getCollection('_survey.response').aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$Agent.Name",
            Suggestions: {$push:"$Agent.Suggestion"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "GhazanferAgent",
    "Suggestions" : [ 
        [ 
            "Clarity", 
            "Effort"
        ], 
        [ 
            "Friendliness"
        ]
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "NomanAgent",
    "Suggestions" : [ 
        [ 
            "Knowledge", 
            "Professionalisn"
        ]
    ]
}
```

How I want it to be(As Suggestion in the document is an array and when when i group documents by Agent.Name so it become array of arrays as shown in my output, it want to merge all arrays into single with duplication and then i will find the count of each element in array):

```
/* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : "GhazanferAgent",
        "SuggestionsCombined" : [ 
            [ 
                "Clarity", 
                "Effort",
                "Friendliness"
            ]
        ]
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : "NomanAgent",
        "SuggestionsCombined" : [ 
            [ 
                "Knowledge", 
                "Professionalisn"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be like this - the output structure is not identical to what you suggested but probably close enough:

```
db.getCollection('_survey.response').aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$Agent.Suggestion" // flatten "Suggestion" array
    }, {
        $group:{ // group by agent and suggestion
            _id: { "AgentName": "$Agent.Name", "Suggestion": "$Agent.Suggestion" },
            "Count": { $sum: 1} // calculate count of occurrencs
        }
    }, {
        $group:{
            _id: "$_id.AgentName", // group by agent only
            "Suggestions": { $push: { "Suggestion": "$_id.Suggestion", "Count": "$Count" } } // create array of "Suggestion"/"Count" pairs per agent
        }
    }
]);
```